# Inconsistent data interval, create regular interval values between known points

Tags: excel, database, graph

I have a list of data points for given depths. Each depth is assigned a character.

My problem is that the data points are at inconsistent intervals, sometimes they can be 1m apart, sometimes 100m.

What I'd like to create is a list for every 1m interval, based on the values I already know. Every depth that is not included in the original data set will have the same character assigned to it as the depth above until the next known depth is reached.

[image: Example of what i have and what i want to achieve]

Hopefully it's not to difficult but I'm rather useless at this kind of thing in excel so any answers can't expect too much prior knowledge :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula, which says 'If exact match for depth, use code for that, otherwise find largest depth less than current depth and use code corresponding to next depth after that'.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$3:B$8,MATCH(D3,A$3:A$8,0)),INDEX(B$3:B$8,MATCH(D3,A$3:A$8)+1))
```

The depth values just increment as follows:

```
=IF(ROW()=3,A3,D2+1)
```

[image]